# How can I declare null array in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have the following code in PHP `public static $bitValueTable = null;` and I want to convert it into Kotlin. My variable is a null array in the first step but I add some value after the program runs.
how can I convert?

Comment: Why do you need a `null` array? Probably your code could be rewritten in such a way that you don't need it, maybe by using an empty array or by delaying the variable creation until you have a value

Comment: I am trying to convert one PHP project to Kotlin and I want to be everything the same in both. this array depends on users and is used in multi-place so I don't know when it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kotlin you can use nullable objects with the secure call operator "?".
Now, you have a static variable in PHP, in kotlin there is no "static" as such, however the companion object {} fulfills the same function.
In this way the equivalent of `public static $bitValueTable = null;`
in kotlin is: 

`companion object {
        var bitValueTable : Array<Type>? = null
    }`

Obs:

- The default value of the variables in kotlin is public

Answer (score 1):

By default any variable in kotlin can't hold null values but still you can create nullable object using `?` operator, for better understanding check below url
 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html.
So to create nullable array use below syntax

```
var myTypeArray: Array<type>? = null // check below example
var myStrArray: Array<String>? = null
```

[Kotlin Arrays Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays)

Thanks

Comment: thanks for answer but there is a static keyword. how can I handle that?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are no static members in Kotlin. Instead, a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) should be used.